# domain suddenly stops browsing and displays default cgi page

Tags: symfony, dns

i am surprised, domain stopped suddenly browsing and it shows default cgi page.

www.eddsp.gov.np not working properly. but sometimes its content page loads correctly like eddsp.gov.np/contact loads perfectly while cgi error comes in eddsp.gov.np | Again sometimes eddsp.gov.np/contact shows 404 error.

while if same site content loaded from subdomain
eddsp.imagingtrade.com.np
it works fine everytime and in every condition.

Answer (score 0):

I came to know that it's caused by A record. Which are changing time to time. After talking with my DNS Providers. They had corrected it.